# Consume the OData service in C# doesn't work

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, odata, crud

I tried to understand this tutorial: http://odata.github.io/odata.net/#OData-Client-Code-Generation-Tool

I can generate the proxy without any problems. Just as it is described.

But at chapter "Consume the OData service" it doesn't work. I have named the application and the proxy exactly as shown in the tutorial. **How can I make odata available in namespace Microsoft?**

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8N8eJ.png)

- Error    CS0234  The type or namespace name 'OData' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) TrippinApp  C:\TrippinApp\Program.cs    6   Active
- Error    CS0246  The type or namespace name 'DefaultContainer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  TrippinApp  C:\TrippinApp\Program.cs    16  Active
- Error    CS0246  The type or namespace name 'DefaultContainer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  TrippinApp  C:\TrippinApp\Program.cs    16  Active

I used:

- Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 (Trial)
- Microsoft.Data.Edm v5.8.3
- Microsoft.Data.Odata v5.8.3
- Microsoft.Data.Services.Client v5.8.3
- System.Spatial v.5.8.3
- WCF Data Services 5.6 Tools (are installed)

## continuation:

**@Evandro Paula:Thank you for your help! I have come a little further thanks to your help. But unfortunately I have not come to the goal yet.**

I installed/updated:

- Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 (15.7.1) (Trial)
- Microsoft.Data.Edm v5.8.3 (I have not found a more recent one)
- Microsoft.Data.Odata v5.8.3 (I have not found a more recent one)
- Microsoft.Data.Services.Client v5.8.3 (I have not found a more recent one)
- Microsoft.OData.Client v7.4.4 (installed)
- Microsoft.OData.Core v7.4.4 (installed)
- Microsoft.OData.Edm v7.4.4 (installed)
- Microsoft.Spatial v7.4.4 (installed)
- System.Spatial v.5.8.3 (I have not found a more recent one)
- WCF Data Services 5.6 Tools (are installed)
  [Screenshot of NuGet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWU8v.png)

**Now the results look like this:**

[Compiling works with Proxy (TrippinProxy.cs), but without Odata example. (Screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8G6Pe.png)

[As soon as I copy the code from the tutorial, compiling does't work anymore. (Screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqmHl.png)

```
using System;
using Microsoft.OData.SampleService.Models.TripPin;

namespace TrippinApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DefaultContainer dsc = new DefaultContainer(
                new Uri("http://services.odata.org/V4/(S(fgov00tcpdbmkztpexfg24id))/TrippinServiceRW/"));
            var me = dsc.Me.GetValue();
            Console.WriteLine(me.UserName);
        }
    }
}
```

source: http://odata.github.io/odata.net/#OData-Client-Code-Generation-Tool

[Now the Namespace Microsoft.OData is found. But not Microsoft.OData.SampleService (Screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8xXR.png)

**[I need a little example. How can I initialize the proxy and add a product (CreateProduct)? Or how can I get the example from the tutorial up and running?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cV7mu.png)**

Answer (score 2):

First, update the packages you mentioned on your question to their latest version. It looks like Visual Studio didn't use the latest version in your case. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise Edition (version 15.7.3) for this test.

- Microsoft.OData.Client (version 7.4.4)
- Microsoft.OData.Core (version 7.4.4)
- Microsoft.OData.Edm (version 7.4.4)
- Microsoft.Spatial (version 7.4.4)

Once the packages are up to date, you will observe the following **build error**, which is related to issue https://github.com/OData/lab/issues/80:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'EdmxReader' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.OData.Edm.Csdl' (are you missing an assembly reference?) ODataClient C:\temp\NET\ODataClient\Connected Services\TrippingService\TrippingProxy.cs 510 Active
```

The **resolution** for this issue is available at https://github.com/juliopinto15/lab/commit/deb1254301a775eb6771b0bed672dd3f56f37cfe.

Just change the proxy (e.g. TrippingProxy.cs) generated code line below as part of method **LoadModelFromString()**:

```
return global::Microsoft.OData.Edm.Csdl.EdmxReader.Parse(reader);
```

to

```
return global::Microsoft.OData.Edm.Csdl.CsdlReader.Parse(reader);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I continued my question because I do not have a solution yet.

Comment: Sure. Can you open the TrippingProxy.cs and ensure the namespace is correct. Also, did you try creating a clean project? I have not observed this error you bumped into.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I deleted the NuGet cache folder, and it compiles now.

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Nuget\v3-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem and user3137104's solution worked for me, but I want to elaborate more on the circumstances since Sebastian Widz's comment suggests some confusion.
I was following [this Microsoft tutorial on getting started with OData clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/client/getting-started). This is with

- Visual Studio 2022 (preview)
- .Net 6
- OData Connected Service 2022+ v1.0.2

When researching for this answer, I followed the tutorial exactly and connected to `https://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinServiceRW/$metadata`, in which case it worked. The namespace existed:

```
Microsoft.OData.SampleService.Models.TripPin
```

and I was able to call:

```
var context = new DefaultContainer(new Uri(serviceRoot));
```

Using the default settings when adding the OData Connected Service, these definitions can be found in `Reference.cs`. This is missing in OP's screenshot (something might have gone wrong when adding the connected service, but the linked tutorial isn't available anymore, so I can't quite comprehend the original problem).

However, what caused me to end up on this thread, is that I immediately tried to connect to a **different endpoint** (instead of `https://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinServiceRW/$metadata`; I had created my own local server) when following the tutorial and adding an OData Connected Service. Obviously (in hindsight), the above mentioned namespace was **not** availabe. But, what was more confusing, is that `DefaultContainer` was also **not** available. Instead, I had to call

```
var context = new Default.Container(new Uri(serviceRoot));
```

where `Default` is a namespace and `Container` a class within that namespace defined in `Reference.cs`

On a side note, `Default.Container` is also availabe when using the TripPin sample.

To reiterate, the relevant definitions can be found in **`Reference.cs`** (auto-generated using default values on the OData Connected Servce).

Answer (score -1):

I worked with the same example (TripPinService) and got the same error. It looks like there is an error in the sample.

Instead of:

```
var context = new DefaultContainer(new Uri(serviceRoot));
```

You need to write:

```
var context = new Default.Container(new Uri(serviceRoot));
```

After that code runs without errors

Comment: Neither of this solutions works. What is "Default"  ?? is this a namespace??